# MariaDB timezone wrong

Tags: cakephp, centos, timezone, mariadb

`SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'time_zone'` returns:

```
Variable_name | Value
time_zone       SYSTEM
```

On the Centos 7 server `timedatectl` returns:

```
      Local time: Fr 2020-09-25 20:24:14 CEST
  Universal time: Fr 2020-09-25 18:24:14 UTC
        RTC time: n/a
       Time zone: Host (CEST, +0200)
```

Inserting a new row into a table with the `DATETIME` type and default value `current_timestamp()` this field has the UTC time [in this case *2020-09-25 18:24:14* instead of *2020-09-25 20:24:14*].

**My question:**

What am I doing wrong? I know how I can set the timezone but the `SYSTEM` value should be OK as the Centos 7 server has the correct timezone set.

**UPDATE**

1)

Answering a comment, `SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone, @@SESSION.time_zone;` returns for 1st `SYSTEM` and 2nd '+00:00'. I am running it under PHP in a Plesk environment.

2)

In the beginning the table didn't have this DATETIME field. When I added it with PMA then the inserted datetime [because the field was defined as `NOT NULL`] was correct! Only when I run the `INSERT` statement then it inserts the UTC time.

Comment: Check your session/vs global timezone with `SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone, @@SESSION.time_zone;` ?

Comment: I believe the issue is due to missing timezone data in `mysql` database. See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html#time-zone-installation). Check if timezone data there with `SELECT * FROM mysql.time_zone;`

Comment: @DanilaVershinin Yes, the table is empty but I don't really believe this is the reason.`SYSTEM` returns the correct time and there shouldn't be the need to modify it. Check my question, I added a 2nd Update.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin The `SELECT` from your 1st comment returns for the PHP session `+00:00` and this is now exactly the problem. I must figure out how to change it in the PHP session.

Comment: I'd actually [recommend](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/configure-time-centos-8) setting the server timezone to UTC. This saves a lot of headache in the long run. Most PHP frameworks (as in your case cakephp also) are timezone-aware. So in most cases "server timezone = UTC" + "app timezone = your desired", will yield proper results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Danila Vershinin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285069/danila-vershinin), I could find the problem. It was his question what `SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone, @@SESSION.time_zone;` returns that got me in the right direction.

First, I ran the command in PMA which returned for both `SYSTEM`. Inserting rows in PMA generated correct time. It was only wrong in my PHP scripts which are running under CakePHP and then I checked the settings in `app_local.php` and there was indeed `UTC` as the `timezone`. Changing `timezone` to `SYSTEM` fixed it.

What should I say, MariaDB works as it should and due to the default CakePHP `timezone` settings I ran into this issue. I added now to the question also the `cakephp` tag as it was the reason for the issue.